# Is there a way to escalate a bug on Launchpad?

Tags: networking, network-manager, launchpad, community

I am wondering if there is a way to escalate bugs on Launchpad or otherwise call attention to them from the developer(s) responsible for maintaining the affected components. I am specifically thinking of [this networking issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1574347) which has been plaguing me and several others for many months. The status of the bug is 'fix released' but as you can see I and many other users have still been experiencing the problem.

I have added a comment on top of the several others that have been posted since it was erroneously marked 'fix-released' but I'm wondering if there's anything else I can do. I don't want to file a new bug because there is already a wealth of diagnostic information in the existing one.

Comment: I would think that the more people it affects and they star it that it affects them will push it up quicker.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: As far as your question goes, Terrance already noted properly that the more people affected by this, the more attention it gets. There's no other way for one. Networking issues are difficult to troubleshoot, so give it time. Consider installing latest version of network manager manually imstead of waiting for update to arrive. Also consider switching to wicd network manager.

Comment: I have asked this question on Launchpad and I will write an answer when I get a response from the Launchpad devs.

Comment: In the mentioned bug people report unrelated issues. A bug should be about one concrete issue otherwise nobody can fix it because it isn't even clear what the problem is. The original issue is resolved, it is not helpful to comment on a closed bug with an very likely different issue. Admittedly it can be hard to identify whether two issues have the same cause. As the original report is closed, there is a strong indication that the issues are indeed different.